# Leaflet with Vuetify 3

Tags: leaflet, vuetify.js

I can't seem to get a leaflet map to display properly with Vuetify 3. Here's my map component:

```html
<template>
    <div id="map"></div>
</template>

<script>
import L from 'leaflet';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            map: null
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.map = L.map('map').setView([47.3293, -122.5801], 11);
        L.tileLayer('https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.{ext}', {
            minZoom: 0,
            maxZoom: 20,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.stadiamaps.com/" target="_blank">Stadia Maps</a> &copy; <a href="https://openmaptiles.org/" target="_blank">OpenMapTiles</a> &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            ext: 'png'
        }).addTo(this.map);
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
@import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

#map {
    height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

The map doesn't display properly:

[image]

I do not want to use a third-party library like  `vue-leaflet`. Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: I am using Leaflet successfully with Vuetify. I'm using OpenStreetMap tiles so can't comment on your use of Stadiamaps tiles. The only other difference is I have the css import in the script, not in the style .